# Angular- Reactive Forms: How to validate fields after patchValue

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form with sub-forms using ControlValueAccessor

profile-form.component.ts

```
form: FormGroup;
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        firstName: [],
        lastName: ["", Validators.maxLength(10)],
        email: ["", Validators.required]
      });

get lastNameControl() {
    return this.form.controls.lastName;
  }

initForm() {
    ...
       this.form.patchValue({
        firstName: "thompson",
        lastName: "vilaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
        email: "abc@gmail.com"
      });
    ...
  }
```

profile-form.component.html

```
<label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
    <input formControlName="lastName" id="last-name" />
    <div *ngIf="lastNameControl.touched && lastNameControl.invalid" class="error">
      last name max length is 10
    </div>
```

Problem:

The initial data are loaded to the form, but the validations are not triggered (for example: field Last Name is not validated). I have to touch the field then the validation start working.

How to trigger validations right after the `patchValue` done.

please refer to the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wg5mxz?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: After the patch you can call this.form.updateValueAndValidity()

Comment: @MikeOne No need to call the updateValueAndValidity(), pathValue method itself call it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To prevent the validator from displaying errors before the user has a chance to edit the form, you should check for either the dirty or touched states in a control.
>
> When the user changes the value in the watched field, the control is marked as "dirty".
> When the user blurs the form control element, the control is marked as "touched".

You should delete `lastNameControl.touched` from your `*ngIf`

Check https://angular.io/guide/form-validation for more information

Answer (score 0):

Its only because you are showing the error when lastName or email is touched as @godocmat mentioned. If you just remove the lastNameControl.touched or emailControl.touched from *ngIf, it works.
Check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xced6b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fprofile-form%2Fprofile-form.component.html